# checking out a SVN repository which has imported directory with symlinks

Tags: svn, version-control

I have imported a local directory in my svn repository using

```
import /my/home/dir file://my/home/svn/repo/trunk
```

The /my/home/dir has files which are symlinks, now when i do a svn co i get symbolic links only (as expected ), but i want the actual files to be checked out. Is this possibles ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. On check-in SVN only saved the contents of the link files (the location of the file you have linked to), but not the contents of the linked-to file, so you can't check the contents out.

Comment: is there any way to import in svn following symlinks?